# How to call google map api from c code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to call google map api from C code?

Comment: What exactly you want to do with API? If you just want geolocation service, than you can access it via http quiries.

Comment: I too have the same question. How do we really call a google map api and displace a map using c language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the [google maps static api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) using HTTP calls.