# Getting map location with the coordinates using C language

Tags: c, google-maps, geolocation

Is it possible to get the location of a place using the latitude and longitude with the C Language? If so how?

Comment: I think it can be done in at least one language. Because there are softwares which do that, and those softwares are written in at least one language. I think it can be done in C also but why would you want to do it in C ? You want C program to display a map and to locate a place in that map ? Something like google map ?

Answer (score 0):

the pair of values [latitude, longitude] can define any place on the earth.

What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Is it possible to find the place on map with the given coordinates in C language?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to usually be more explicit of what you need. For example getting the coordinates in C can be as simple as passing two float variables for latitude and longitude. You only added a reference to google-maps in the tags so in the future please add that also to the text here so it is easier to see and not miss.

The google-maps API does not support C by default, but you can make HTTP calls to the static API.
A really quick search revealed this.
You can write a simple C program that sends the coordinates via HTTP to the Google Maps static API and returns your location.

Here is how to access the static google-maps HTTP API:
[Google Maps Static API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025602/how-to-call-google-map-api-from-c-code)

Here is an example of how to do HTTP requests from C:
[HTTP requests from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802/simple-c-example-of-doing-an-http-post-and-consuming-the-response)

Here is a page from google that can help you decide what API for maps to use depending on you needs:
[Google Maps API Picker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker)